# Autofocus on input area hidden in modal box

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using [Fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to create modal boxes for my website.

There is a login form in one of the modal boxes, and when I click the "login button", I want to have it autofocus on the first input area, but the `autofocus="yes"` attribute isn't working for me, so I can't have it autofocus. Is this because this login box is `display:none`, then turned into `display: block` using Fancybox2, or is there another reason for it not being able to autofocus on a desired box?

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `afterShow:` callback in fancy box like ,

```
 $(".fancybox")    
    .fancybox({
        afterShow: function () {
           $("#loginfield").focus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The form should be visible before you can `focus` on any form field so try `afterShow` instead. Check http://jsfiddle.net/qcYQy/